# Why Doesn't Compound Clip With Effect in One Project Still Have Effect When Placed in Another Project?

Tags: editing, final-cut-pro-x, effects, fcpx

In project **A** I have grouped a number of clips into a compound clip called **c1**. While in project **A** I've added to the compound clip (e.g. so it affects the entire compound clip) a *color board* effect and some *transformation* adjustments.

Then when I go into project **B** and insert compound clip **c1** it does not have the effect or transformation adjustments.

Is there a way for the adjustments I've made in project **A** to transfer over to project **B**? I have something like 200 compound clips along these lines that need to get reassembled in another project, and I don't want to lose all those adjustments.

Finally, is there anything else that doesn't transfer over I should be aware of?

Comment: Is project B in the same library?

Comment: Yes, all of this is in the same library.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you duplicated your project as a snapshot. Taking a snapshot of a project will duplicate the whole project but also a separate copy of the compound clips within a project. This way you can change anything on a compound clip in Project A, and it won't effect project B.

Here is a quote [**from the docs**](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH15846?locale=en_US):

> When you duplicate a project as a snapshot, Final Cut Pro embeds copies of compound or multicam “parent” clips in the snapshot, so any changes to other instances of those clips do not affect the snapshot.